# css 100% height body doesn't cover whole document

Tags: html, css

I tried to create HTML document with one layer in center like that:

```
<body>
 <div id="background">
  LONG TEXT HERE
 </div>
</body>
```

and I set

```
html, body  {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #color1;
}
```

and

```
#background  {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10%;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 10%;
    background-color: #color2;
    top: 0px; 
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

But somehow if the text exceed height of the display and when I scroll down there is no background. I have checked in FireBug it looks like if the whole document is only the size of the initial window.
I need to make it 100% height. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove height: 100%; and position: absolute;

It will work. Like below

```
#background  {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10%;
  background-color: #093;
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: not wrong, but a bad habit, please try to avoid it because 0 does not need a unit. 0Kg == 0px

Answer (score 2):

If the text is longer than the page, you will need to set the `overflow` property in CSS - otherwise elements will expand to fit their contents.

For example:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Although this would make some text invisible, so you may want to use `auto` not `hidden` depending on what you are doing.

Comment: my solution was to use overflow:auto; on the html&body tag, and use absolute positioning with left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0; that way it covers the body tag and scrolling is contained in the body